# How can you legally perform the mod operator on a rounded double?

Tags: c++, casting, double, clang, modulo

I am trying to implement the mod operator on a double that is temporarily converted to an integer (rounded), but the compiler (clang) doesn't seem to like that and returns the error: `assignment to cast is illegal, lvalue casts are not supported`. 
For example, in this snippet

```
double a;
int b;
(int)a %= b;
```

Is there a way to get around this limitation?

Comment: Use an intermediate int variable

Comment: Look up the `fmod()` function in `<cmath>`.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is illegal. Saying `(int)a = ...` is illegal because you cannot cast `a` to an integer in this way. You must cast it on the right hand side of the assignment.

If you really wanted to do this, you could say:

```
double a;
int b;
a = (double)((int)a % b); /* Casting to a double at this point is useless, but because a is a double-type, the result of the modulus it will be implicitly casted to a double if you leave out the explicit cast. */
```

I would advise assigning the modulus result to a new int variable, but that is your choice to make.

---

**Edit**: Here is an example of this: http://ideone.com/tidngT

Also, it is worth noting that casting a double to an int does not round it, but rather, it just truncates it. And, if the value of your double is higher than the range of an `int`, then this can produce undefined behavior.